# Back substitution and QR Factorisation via Householder

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, regression

I'm having difficulties getting the same beta values from this OLS regression as I would without the QR decomposition. I believe it has to do with the shape of my Q block. I start as so:

A =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 8 \\
1 & 3 & 37 \\
1 & 4 & 64 \\
1 & 5 & 125 \\
\end{pmatrix}

b = \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\2\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}

This gives me an R of:

R = \begin{pmatrix}-2.236&-6.708&-105.095\\0&3.16228&96.1332\\0&0&29.4686\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}

And a Q of:

Q = \begin{pmatrix}-0.447214&-0.632456&0.50223&0.112111&-0.36769166\\-0.447214&-0.316228&-0.29184&0.213736&0.75441948\\-0.447214&-1.39e{-17}&-0.33934&-0.81059&-0.16672608\\-0.447214&0.3162278&-0.45472&0.531518&-0.45903965\\-0.447214&0.6324555&0.58367&-0.04678&0.2390379\end{pmatrix}

It is my understanding that to get the beta values (x) you need to use back substitution. The thing is, with a square Q, the last two values from $Q^{T}$b values that are not used.

Rx = $Q^{T}$b

\begin{pmatrix}-2.236&-6.708&-105.095\\0&3.16228&96.1332\\0&0&29.4686\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix}X\\X\\X\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-4.472136\\1.26491106\\0.08144254\\-0.158891\\0.60672956\end{pmatrix}

By my substitution I am getting betas (X) of

\begin{pmatrix}0.9222\\0.3160\\0.0028\end{pmatrix}

When I should be getting:

\begin{pmatrix}0.8966\\0.3365\\0.0021\end{pmatrix}

If I do the standard OLS equation I get the correct betas without a problem. It must be something with my factorisation?

I'd greatly appreciate any help. I think the problem is the square nature of my Q matrix, but that is how following the guides below result.

I based my process on this stackexchange page:
[How can I compute solution of a non-square matrix by QR Decomposition and Cholesky Factorization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076373/how-can-i-compute-solution-of-a-non-square-matrix-by-qr-decomposition-and-choles)

And this Lecture:
http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat610/sum10/lecture9.pdf

Comment: I got the same $A = QR$ as you, but don't have time to continue.

Comment: I'm confused where you are having the problem. Are you doing this by hand? Do you have code?

Comment: I don’t think it’s in the computations, I’ve been doing it in excel right now, I think it’s in the process. If Moo got the same QR then either the process outlined in paper/stackexchange is not right or I’m missing something in back substitution. I can upload the excel sheets tonight if it would help